# Autocompletar formulario html sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html5

Bien, estoy creando un sistema para el control de comedores, realmente soy nuevo en esto, sin embargo me gusta aprender, les explico mi problema tengo un lector de codigo de barra lee una "tarjeta" e inserta el codigo en un input, quisiera que al leer la tarjeta e insertar dicho codigo lo busque en la base de datos y autocomplete los datos de ese empleado en otros input, valla me muestre su informacion y ademas inserte un registro de checada de comida en mi base de datos, a continuacion describo el codigo como lo tengo escrito:

```
<?php
/*-------------------------
Autor: INNOVAWEBSV
Web: www.innovawebsv.com
Mail: info@innovawebsv.com
---------------------------*/
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND 
$_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
    }

require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion 
para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la 
base de datos
$active_facturas="active";
$active_productos="";
$active_clientes="";
$active_usuarios="";    
$title="Facturas | Simple Invoice";
if(isset($_POST['grabar'])){

    $no_emp= $_POST['no_emp'];
}
$query_empresa=mysqli_query($con,"select * from empleados where 
no_emp='$no_emp'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_empresa);
?>
```

esto de arriba es el incio del codigo donde esta la conexion a la base de datos y la verificacion de que el usuario inicio sesion, despues un query para alamcenar datos en variables "row".

En el codigo HTML esta lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php include("head.php");?>


  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    include("navbar.php");
    ?> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> Configuración</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post" id="perfil">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 toppad" >



            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">

              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  id="datos_cotizacion">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="q" class="col-md-2 control-label">Departamento o # de empleado</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Nombre del departamento # de empleado" onkeyup='load(1);'>
                            </div>



                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='load(1);'>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span> Buscar</button>
                                <span id="loader"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>


            </form>
            <form name="noemp" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"> 
                <div id="load_img">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $row['img_emp'];?>" alt="Logo">

                </div>
                <br>                
                    <div class="row">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 "> 
                  <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_perfil" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class='col-md-3'>No Emp:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="no_emp" id="no_emp" value="" required></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Nombre:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="nombre_emp" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Departamento:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="dep_emp" value="<?php echo $row['dep_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Confidencialidad:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="empresa_emp" value="<?php echo $row['empresa_emp']?>" readonly></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Fecha de Ingreso:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime($row['ing_emp'])) ?>" readonly></td>
                      </tr>



                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-12' id="resultados_ajax"></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
              </div>
            </div>



                            <button type="submit" class="hidden" name="grabar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Actualizar datos</button>




          </div>
        </div>
        </form>

                <div id="resultados"></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
                <div class='outer_div'></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>
    <hr>
    <?php
    include("footer.php");
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/VentanaCentrada.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checadas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.js"> </script>
<script>
$( "#perfil" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $('.guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

 var parametros = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/registro_checadas.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('.guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);

          }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
})






    </script>
    <script>
   $( "#perfil" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $('.guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

 var parametros = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/buscar_checadas.php",
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('.guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);

          }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
})






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

El detalle es que no se como hacer que busque en la base de datos con el codigo que se inserta en el input de numero de empleado (que se inserta mediante el lector de código de barras), se que debo poner la variable en

`$query_empresa=mysqli_query($con,"select * from empleados where no_emp='AQUI VA LA VARIABLE'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_empresa);`

Pero no se como almacenar el dato del input en una variable para usarlo como criterio de busqueda y a su vez me muestre los datos, no se si me explico, dejo una

> [archivo con mis codigos](https://mega.nz/#!F4JiEKSQ!F26avqm-hY0hz1WE2wO8J9uIjIZxSgY5rmCer3gFY5k)

, espero puedan ayudarme ya me duele la cabeza de tanto pensar jaja, saludos!

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. Este código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar inyección SQL te recomendaría algo así:

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("select * from empleados where 
    no_emp = ?");
//binding de los parámetros (i se refiere a enteros)
$sentencia->bind_param("i", $no_emp );
$sentencia->execute();

$row = $sentencia->get_result();
//...
```